# Store a Swift function and its parameter values and call it later

Tags: swift

There are multiple functions in my app, where each have a different number of parameters

```
func functionOne(foo: Foo, bar: Bar)

func functionTwo(foo: Foo, bar: Bar, baz: Baz, quux: Quux)

func functionThree(foo: Foo)
```

The parameter values can vary.

My requirement is to press a button which will run whichever function of the above was run most recently, including its parameter values.

Storing the whole thing (function and parameters) in a variable did not work.

Answer (score 7):

A function and its parameters are stored in a closure. For example:

```
func f(_ x: Int) {}
func g(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {}

var saved: () -> Void = { f(1) }

saved() // this executes f(1)

saved = { g(2, 3) }

saved() // now this executes g(2, 3)
```

Comment: Good answer! Just needs a tweak: var saved: () -> Void = { f(x: 1) }

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@escaping` and `@autoclosure` to store a function and its parameters as a closure in a property of your `class` and then call it.

Add this class to your project:

```
// Stored Function Class
class SFC {
    static var calledFunc: (() -> Void)?

    static func call(_ function: @escaping @autoclosure () -> Void) {
        // Store the function
        calledFunc = function

        // Call it
        function()
    }

    static func reCall() {
        // Called the stored function
        calledFunc?()
    }

    // Call this when you no longer want SFC to hold onto your function.
    // Your class will not deallocate if you passed in `self` to `call()`
    // as long as `calledFunc` retains your function.  Setting it to `nil`
    // frees it.
    static func forget() {
        calledFunc = nil
    }
}
```

**This is how you use it:**

Wrap any function call that you want to repeat with `SFC.call()`.  Call `SFC.reCall()` to call that function again.

**Example:**

```
func add(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) {
    print("\(a) + \(b) = \(a + b)")
}

SFC.call(print("hello", "bye"))
SFC.reCall()
SFC.reCall()
SFC.call(add(2, 3))
SFC.reCall()
```

**Output:**

> ```
> hello bye
> hello bye
> hello bye
> 2 + 3 = 5
> 2 + 3 = 5
> ```

---

**How does this work?**

The contents of the call to `call()` are automatically wrapped in a closure (that is what `@autoclosure` does) and passed as `function`.  The `@escaping` means that you'll be hanging onto that closure after `call()` returns.

That closure is then assigned to the `calledFunc` property so that it can be called again later from `reCall()`.

**Note:**  If the function you are passing to `call()` is a member function, you'll need to explicitly specify `self`.  For example: `SFC.call(self.functionThree(foo: fooVar))`.  Be sure to call `SFC.forget()` when it's time for your class to be freed so that `SFC` doesn't hold onto your class instance.